# Define base class constructor methods in derived classes

Tags: c#, inheritance, abstract-class

I am trying to create a comprehensive `abstract` `BaseClass` that defines the way in which all derived classes are created, but allows derived classes to specialize/aggregate the fields and methods used in the creation process.  Here is a simplified example:

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public List<String> list;

    public BaseClass()
    {
        defineList();
        optionalDoSomething();
        doSomething();
    }

    protected void defineList()
    {
        list = new List<String>();
    }

    protected void doSomething()
    {
        // do something w/ list here
    }

    protected void optionalDoSomething() {}
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    protected void defineList()
    {
        base.defineList();
        list.Add("something");
    }

    public DerivedClass() : base() { }
}

public class SecondDerivedClass : DerivedClass
{
    protected void defineList()
    {
        base.defineList();
        list.Add("somethingElse");
    }

    protected void optionalDoSomething()
    {
        // do something special
    }

    public SecondDerivedClass() : base() { }
}
```

This would free all derived classes from having to recreate the same initialization logic, and each derived class would only need to "overwrite" the necessary fields and methods used in the create process (and possibly elsewhere in the class).

The problem:

1. I cannot mark `BaseClass`' methods as `virtual` since you cannot call `virtual` methods in a base constructor (in any case, I would not want to use `virtual` methods since, for example, I would not want `DerivedClass` to use `SecondDerivedClass`' `defineList` method).
2. I can mark them `abstract`, but then I would not be able to put "default implementations" in `BaseClass` and each derived class would have to replicate/implement those defaults.  Also, `SecondDerived` class would still need a way to "override" the implementations of `DerivedClass`.
3. It does not work to simply use the `new` key word "hide" less derived class' methods.

What is the correct way to obtain this pattern?

TLDR: as per my comment below:
If `BaseClass` is an `abstract` class with method `A`, and `DerivedClass` is a class derived from `BaseClass` (not necessarily a direct child of `BaseClass`), then calling `A` in `BaseClass`' constructor should call `A()` in every class in the inheritance hierarchy up to and including `DerivedClass` (but no further).  We can assume that `A` (forced to be) defined on every intermediate class.

Comment: I don't really understand your question. First of all, while certainly _not recommended_ it is legal to call virtual members from the constructor. Second, in your example, the only thing the `defineList()` methods are doing is adding elements to the `list` field (which should not be `public`, and frankly in most scenarios would be _`private`_, not even `protected`), which you could just as easily do in each sub-class's constructor. In other scenarios, you would simply pass initialized data from the more-derived constructors down to the base class constructors.

Comment: I will not call `virtual` methods in the constructor.  Also, this is a simplified example, but in general, the methods called in `BaseClass`' constructor could do other things.  Ultimately, `BaseClass`' constructor should "accumulate" some data and then call methods that process that data.  Since the processing of that data will be the same for *most* derived classes, those classes will only need to provide more data (e.g. `defineList`) before a "processing" method is called (e.g. `doSomething`).  Allowing derived classes to "overwrite" other methods will not happen often.

Comment: "the methods called in BaseClass' constructor could do other things" -- then please provide a code example that illustrates those "other things". As the question's been asked so far, all you've got is a non-problem. It certainly will lead (and has led) to a number of attempts to answer, but as you can see, the suggestions are all over the board, and without a clear problem statement, it's hard to see how the question and answers could prove useful in general to others.

Comment: The point is that the solution should be independent of those "other things" otherwise I would have specified more detail.  If you are looking for a simpler, more specific statement, please see the "TLDR".  I do not agree that I have a "non-problem".  If the attempts to an answer are "all over the board," perhaps that is because what I am asking is non-trivial or has no (good) solution.  In this case, I refer you to my statement "What is the correct way to obtain this pattern?".  Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you should refer to [template-method-design-pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/net/template-method-design-pattern)

> Define the skeleton of an algorithm in an operation, deferring some
>   steps to subclasses. Template Method lets subclasses redefine certain
>   steps of an algorithm without changing the algorithm's structure.

you can try something similar to this

```
abstract class AbstractClass
  {
    public List<String> list;
    public abstract void PrimitiveOperation1();

    public void TemplateMethod()
    {
      //initialize code that each class should perform
      PrimitiveOperation1();
    }
  }

class DerivedClass: AbstractClass
  {
    public override void PrimitiveOperation1()
    {
      list.Add("something");
    }
  }
```

usage

```
AbstractClass abstractClass1 = new DerivedClass();
abstractClass1.TemplateMethod();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution, the implementation is implemented with protected virtual methods, so its not visible from the outside and not required in derived classes:

```
    public abstract class BaseClass
    {
        public List<String> List { get; protected set; }

        protected BaseClass()
        {
            defineList();
            optionalDoSomething();
            doSomething();
        }

        protected void defineList()
        {
            // default implementation here
            List = new List<String>();

            internalDefineList();
        }

        protected void doSomething()
        {
            // default implementation here
            internalDoSomething();
        }

        protected void optionalDoSomething()
        {
            // default implementation here
            internalOptionalSomething();
        }

        protected virtual void internalDefineList()
        {
        }

        protected virtual void internalDoSomething()
        {
        }

        protected virtual void internalOptionalSomething()
        {
        }
    }

    public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
    {
        protected override void internalDefineList()
        {
            var list = List;
        }

        protected override void internalDoSomething()
        {
        }

        // this method is not required
        /*          
        protected override void internalOptionalSomething()
        {
        }
        */
    }
```

Comment: This is close and good(!), but if I subclass `DerivedClass`, say `SecondDerivedClass : DerivedClass`, and `override` an "internal" method there, then any instance of `DerivedClass` will call `SecondDeriveClass`' "internal".  Basically, if a class derives from `BaseClass` and has method `A`, then calling `A` from that derived class should call `A` on all less derived classes up to and including `BaseClass`... and it should not call `A` on any "more derived" classes.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve what you want is to add an explicit `Initialize` method to the base class and do the initializaiton logic there, e.g:

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public List<String> list;

    public BaseClass()
    {

    }

    public void Initialize()
    {
        defineList();
        optionalDoSomething();
        doSomething();
    }
}
```